# how to write 3 conditions in MongoDB query?

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

```
db.mycollection.find({"$and": [{"key1": value1}, {"key2": value2}]})
```

This is for 2 filterd condtions

I also have **key3** and **value3**. How can I query for a third condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `$and` into `find` stage, you can add different keys in the object like this:

```
db.collection.find({
  "key1": 1,
  "key2": 2,
  "key3": 3
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7RzlrC9J69Z).

By the way, to do it using `$and` is only to add one more object into the array, like [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vb78aHSbmBz)

[$and](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) is an array with syntax:

```
{ $and: [ { <expression1> }, { <expression2> } , ... , { <expressionN> } ] }
```

So you can add as many expressions as you want.

Comment: thanks, it worked. 
can I know which is a free tool, that can convert SQL query to NO SQL mongodb query?